# Ligero problema a la hora de subir mi pagina web. �

Tags: base-de-datos, phpmyadmin

soy un poco nuevo en esto, estaba haciendo un proyecto personal, y al momento de subirlo a una web de prueba como cdmon todas las ñ y silabas con tildes se cambiaron por un �, este problema no estaba mientras tenia mi pagina web con xammp, asi que supongo que el problema derive en el momento que subi mi base de datos a la pagina de cdmon, alguien a usado esta pagina que me pueda guiar? tengo entendido que es por la codificacion de caracteres, en donde puedo cambiar eso desde el phpmyadmin?

Comment: Por favor usa títulos más específicos. Cualquier pregunta se podría titular así. Imagina si el título hubiera sido *Tengo un problema con mi código*; es un título que podrían llevar todas las preguntas del sitio ya que la mayoría necesita ayuda con su código.